# Lagest and Smallest number Java console application.Why the console returns 2147483647?

Tags: java, console-application

> This is code which i am write

```
public class School1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        if(num % 2 == 1) {
            sum += num;
            if (num > max) {
                max = num;
            } else if (num < min) {
                min = num;
            }
        }else if(num % 2 == 0){
            sum1 += num;
            if (num > max1) {
                max1 = num;
            } else if (num < min1) {
                min1 = num;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("OddSum =" + sum);
    System.out.println("OddMin = " + min);
    System.out.println("OddMax = " + max);
    System.out.println("EvenSum =" + sum1);
    System.out.println("EvenMin = " + min1);
    System.out.println("EvenMax = " + max1);
}
}
```

> This is exercise in one book and I have to write a console application which takes "n" numbers and returns Even max and Odd max , Even min and Odd min , Even sum and Odd sum
>   Well the code runs and all it's ok but when console returns EvenMin or OddMin = 2147483647 i can't understand why or how to make it run normal ? Someone help? 
>   post-caption : Please don't report the question because i searched for answer.

Comment: Try removing the `else` for min. For example if you enter successively larger numbers, the min part is not executed.

Comment: Also, what do you expect it to print if there are no odds and/or no evens inputted?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp is correct, remove the else statement and just simply have two if statements.

Comment: Okay, thanks I will try now

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved now!

Answer (score 0):

you have to separate these two if conditions

```
if (num > max) {
    max = num;
} 
if (num < min) {
    min = num;
}
```

and your code doesn't work for negative numbers